# Loading XML into memory

Tags: java, xml

I want to read an XML file into memory as a tree of nodes, on which I could perform further operations. Something like C#'s `XDocument`. What is the Java equivalent of C#'s `XDocument.Load`?

Comment: Are you asking about `XDocument` or `XmlDocument`? `XDocument` is part of LINQ to XML, so you're probably not going to find any Java equivalent, as LINQ only exists in .NET

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159047/modern-alternative-to-java-xstream-library for some Java XML libraries. There may be something there that fits your way of working better than plain DOM. Also, Simple (http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#deserialize) seems to be, well, simple to use.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the Java XML [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) classes, which are part of [JAXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAXP). It's much uglier than in C#.

- A [`DocumentBuilderFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html) creates...
- A [`DocumentBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) which creates...
- A [`Document`](http://org.w3c.dom.Document) which is what you're really after.

An excellent reference for all this: the [JAXP Tutorial, Chapter 3: The Document Object Model](http://java.sun.com/webservices/reference/tutorials/jaxp/html/dom.html).