# Unwanted elements in XML via XSTREAM

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xstream

I am new to XStream

I have following DTO

```
@XStreamAlias("outline")
public class OutlineItem implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2321669186524783800L;

    @XStreamAlias("text")
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String text;

    @XStreamAlias("removeMe")
    private List<OutlineItem> childItems;
}
```

once i do

```
XStream stream = new XStream();
stream.processAnnotations(OutlineItem.class);
stream.toXML(outlineItem);
```

i get this as my output text

```
<outline text="Test">
  <removeMe>
    <outline text="Test Section1">
      <removeMe>
        <outline text="Sub Section1 1">
          <removeMe/>
        </outline>
        <outline text="Sub Section1 2">
          <removeMe/>
        </outline>
      </removeMe>
    </outline>
    <outline text="Test Section 2">
      <removeMe>
        <outline text="Test Section2 1">
          <removeMe/>
        </outline>
      </removeMe>
    </outline>
  </removeMe>
</outline>
```

whereas i want the output to be:

```
<outline text="Test">
    <outline text="Test Section1">
        <outline text="Sub Section1 1">
        </outline>
        <outline text="Sub Section1 2">
        </outline>
    </outline>
    <outline text="Test Section 2">
        <outline text="Test Section2 1">
        </outline>
    </outline>
</outline>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Not sure if some kind of XSLT is required...

- Shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead, and a member of the JAXB ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

---

I believe the answer is:

```
@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="outline")
private List<OutlineItem> childItems;
```

Have you considered using a JAXB implementation ([Metro](http://jaxb.java.net/), [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), [JaxMe](http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/), ...) instead?

- [Modern alternative to Java XStream library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159047/modern-alternative-to-java-xstream-library/6161183#6161183)
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

**OutlineItem**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="outline")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OutlineItem implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2321669186524783800L;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String text;

    @XmlElement("outline")
    private List<OutlineItem> childItems;

}
```

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(OutlineItem.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(outlineItem, System.out);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It worked very well. I am also going to look at the JAXB.