# unwanted elements in the xml

Tags: xslt, xml-serialization, xstream

I have following DTO

```
@XStreamAlias("outline")
public class OutlineItem implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2321669186524783800L;

    @XStreamAlias("text")
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String text;

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    @XStreamImplicit
    private List<OutlineItem> childItems;
}
```

once i do

```
XStream stream = new XStream();
stream.processAnnotations(OutlineItem.class);
stream.toXML(outlineItem.getChildItems()); //This is a List of all the child items
```

i get this as my output text

```
<List>
    <outline text="Test Section1">
        <outline text="Sub Section1 1">
        </outline>
        <outline text="Sub Section1 2">
        </outline>
    </outline>
    <outline text="Test Section 2">
        <outline text="Test Section2 1">
        </outline>
    </outline>
</List>
```

whereas i want the output to be:

```
<outline text="Test Section1">
    <outline text="Sub Section1 1">
    </outline>
    <outline text="Sub Section1 2">
    </outline>
</outline>
<outline text="Test Section 2">
    <outline text="Test Section2 1">
    </outline>
</outline>
```

How do i get rid of the Initial List tag? any help is greatly appreciated.

PS> This is a extension of the question i had asked a couple of weeks [back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838312/unwanted-elements-in-xml-via-xstream)

Can this be achieved by XSLT at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XSLT answer is immediate:

- identity transformation (a variant seems enough given your input sample)
- "uncopy" **List** rule

[XSLT 1.0]

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="List">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Actually, the identity rule is quite different from the template you call "identity transformation". Please, correct.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't only terminology. Your so called "identity transformation" doesn't copy to the output certain types of nodes, such as comments and processing instructions. Please, correct the misleading text.

Comment: Completely agree, the only issue with your answer is calling "identity transformation" a template that isn't such. Will you, please, correct?

Comment: I've now described better my text.